# bind a textbox value if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

how to pass a textbox value to controller based on condition .
if checkbox is checked then bind the textbox with object value and pass to the controller other wise just leave it blank and pass the user input to controller.. what i am doing is not working. what is wrong with my code it is working in the case if checkbox is checked.

```
$scope.Product = [
        {"ProductID":12,"LNumber":"hrx",weght:"2"},
        {"ProductID":13,"LNumber":"pty",weght:"1"}
    ]

<div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="Copyknotes" />
  <span >Copy notes from</span>
</div>

<table data-ng-repeat="Item in Product track by $index">                                          
   <tr >
     <td>                                              
        <input type="radio" name="groupName_{{Item.ProductID}}"  data-ng-model ="Item.isSelected"  />
     </td>
     <td data-ng-if="Copyknotes == true">
       <input type="text" data-ng-model="Item.LNumber">
      </td>
      <td data-ng-if="Copyknotes == false" id="hi">
      <input type="text" data-ng-model="Item.LNumber=""">
       </td>
       </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe because Copyknotes is undefined if checkbox is not ticked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

> data-ng-init=""

instead of

```
data-ng-model="Item.LNumber="""
```

use

```
data-ng-model="Item.LNumber"


<table data-ng-repeat="Item in Product track by $index">                                          
   <tr >
     <td>                                              
        <input type="radio" name="groupName_{{Item.ProductID}}"  data-ng-model ="Item.isSelected"  />
     </td>
     <td data-ng-if="Copyknotes == true">
       <input type="text" data-ng-model="Item.LNumber">
      </td>
      <td data-ng-if="Copyknotes == false" id="hi">
      <input type="text" data-ng-model="Item.LNumber" data-ng-init="">
       </td>
       </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `scope.function`

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="Copyknotes" ng-change="changeValue(Copyknotes)" />

//Code should be inside Angular js controller
$scope.changeValue = function(Copyknotes){
   if(Copyknotes)
   {
     //Manipulate text box value here
     $scope.Item.LNumber = 'whatever';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/3Vtl6roWfL1ZqaR2nEvf

```
<td data-ng-if="Copyknotes == false">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="Item.NNumber" ng-init="Item.NNumber = ''">
</td>
```

The expression was wrong - **data-ng-model="Item.LNumber="""** - if you want to assign a new value, you can use Item.LNumber = "''" (two single quotes within double quotes) to avoid interference with tag attribute "" symbols. I've made a live example of how it could be done. Don't know if your controller need original values of input, so new values (when checkbox is unchecked) are saving to NNumber instead. You can freely change them to LNumber if you want. Also, ng-init directive is used to initiate NNumber parameter of object when inputs are rendered into view.
Also you should define Copyknotes to compare. Or write your conditions like ng-if="Copyknotes", ng-if="!Copyknotes".

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="Copyknotes" ng-change="changeValue(Copyknotes)" />
```

first of all remove the data-ng-model and use following:

```
      //Code should be inside Angular js controller
        var oninput = null;
        $scope.changeValue = function(Copyknotes){
           if(Copyknotes)
           { 
             var oninput = document.getElementById("textbox").onchange =function(){
       $scope.item.LNumber = this.value;
           }
             //Manipulate text box value here

           }else{
             $scope.Item.LNumber = '';
             oninput = null 
           }
        }
```